# Is this "moon buggy" an official Lego set?

Tags: set-identification

This six-wheeled "moon buggy" has been in approximately this form in our Lego box since the 1980s. Is it from / based on an official Lego set or something my brother made up?

[image: Lego moon buggy with six wheels]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The distinctive parts of that build are [4288 Wheel Full Rubber Balloon with Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4288) and [3787 Vehicle, Mudguard 2 x 4 with Arch Smooth](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3787) (in old grey colour). They do appear in several classic space sets.

But a [search for sets which contains both of these parts together](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?fromForm=Y&viewMulti=Y&itemType=P&itemNo1=4288&itemSeq1=1&itemNo2=3787&itemSeq2=1&in=S) tells us that your buggy is not an official set.